# What does np.empty((0,shape)) in python mean?

Tags: python, numpy

How can the tuple with shape (0,2) be passed?

```
a = np.empty((0,2))
a
>>> array([], shape=(0, 2), dtype=float64)
```

Also what is the difference between tuple and list while passing the shape as a parameter in np.empty()?

```
arr = np.empty((2,2))
arr
>>> array([[ 0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.]])
arr1 = np.empty([2,2])
arr1
>>> array([[ 0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.]])
```

How both tuple and list gives same output?

Comment: As arguments to `zeros`, `empty`, `ones`, list and tuple do the same thing.  `a,shape` is always a tuple.  Experiment with `np.zeros` or `np.ones` first.  They are easier to visualize.  In general you shouldn't need to create an array with a 0 dimension.  It doesn't contain any values, so isn't very useful.  Don't treat it like an empty list, `[]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing a tuple with 0, such as (0, 2) as shape parameter is allowed, but the resulting array is empty since it contains 0*2 = 0  elements.  Written out in words, it's "zero rows with 2 elements in each row" where "2 elements in each row" is not of much consequence since there are no rows.

Such arrays arise when slicing goes wrong: for example,

```
b = np.ones((2, 2))
a = b[2:, :]
```

makes `a` an array of shape `(0, 2)` as there are no values of the first index that fall in the given slice.  There is no reason to create such arrays intentionally.

There is no difference between `np.empty([2, 2])` and `np.empty((2, 2))`, the array creation method, as many other NumPy methods, accepts a list instead of a tuple. It's still recommended to use tuples for shape parameters, because `arr.shape` is always a tuple.